# how to get possibility data from keras NN?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am learning keras NN with this [tutorial](https://github.com/fastforwardlabs/keras-hello-world/blob/master/kerashelloworld.ipynb)

In the example, we classify the famous IRIS dataset

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_X, train_y_ohe, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=0);
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y_ohe, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy = {:.2f}".format(accuracy))
```

However, I would like to print out the possibility matrix for the testing data (i.e. after applying the Activation('softmax'), what the chance for a testing data belong to class A, B, C, D). Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After training the model, you would want to apply it to your test set.
You can do:

```
class_probability = model.predict(test_X)
```

Consult [here](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> predict(self, x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
>   Generates output predictions for the input samples.

Comment: thanks, the tutorial also uses sklearn to do the same thing. Is there a chance that you know how to get probability matrix in that one?

Comment: Sorry, When I run model.transform(test_X), I got 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'transform'. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I meant .predict(). Edited my answer.